# I messed up with oci ubuntu instance. Cannot connect to instance

Tags: networking, ubuntu

So recently, I was trying to "do-release-upgrade" of Ubuntu 20.04 in my 18.04 instance.
But while upgrading, I accidentally closed my ssh connection. Then I tried to reconnect but I got "connection refused" message and couldn't connect. Also I can't connect to http server running.

I set my ssh port to 22818, but it seems like the iptable rules has been reset while upgrading.
I checked nmap port scan and the only port opened is 22.
But the problem is... the instance has "endlessh" installed which prevents ssh login to port 22.
So I cant even connect to port 22.

I tried cloud shell console connection but it keep saying incorrect login.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I noticed that FTP was running and the port was open. It kept saying login details are incorrect.  I booted this instance to maintenance mode with cloud shell and allowed anonymous mode and I could get all files.

I backed up those files to another temporary instance and restored to fresh one.